# How do I dry up my Rails actionmailer code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm Rails noobie, and I'm trying to build a website that sends different emails based on mouseclicks.  I have a series of 45 different emails, (emsj01, emdr01,...embr45), and I'm trying to write one controller action that sends one of the emails that the user can select from a giant list.

This is my homepage view:

```
<p>Let's send some emails!</p>
<%= link_to 'Send First Email EMDI01', :controller => "showsender", :action => "send_mail", :mailnumber => "emdi01" %>
<p>Here's the next email!</p>
<%= link_to 'Send Second Email EMDR01', :controller => "showsender", :action => "send_mail", :mailnumber => "emdr01" %>
```

and this is my showsender controller:

```
def send_mail
  ShowMailer.mailnumber.deliver_now
  flash[:notice] = "email has been sent."
redirect_to :controller => 'showsender', :action => 'home'
    end
```

and this is my showmailer page:

```
class ShowMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def mailnumber

  end

  def emdr01(tempname)
    @tempname = tempname
    @greeting = tempname.first_name
    mail to: "temp@foo.com", subject: "Happy First Day!", from: "foo@foo.biz"
  end

  def emsj01
    mail to: "temp@foo.com", subject: "Happy Second Day!", from: "foo@foo.biz"
  end
end
```

There is content in my show_mailer views, both in emdi01.html.erb, and in emdio1.text.erb

Comment: Does the view file exist? `app/views/showsender/send_mail.html.erb`? If you don't want one, add `redirect_to root_url` to the bottom of the `send_mail ` method.

Comment: I added the redirect, thanks, but my emails still won't send.

Comment: You need to post the code for `ShowMailer` to be able to solve that problem.

Comment: Hi @Oleander! Here is the entire ShowMailer

Comment: You're calling `mailnumber`, which is an empty function. Try calling `emsj01 ` or `emdr01 ` instead by running `ShowMailer.emsj01.deliver_now`.

Comment: oh RIGHT! So what is the right way to set it up so that the parameters that I pass from my link_to on my homepage get passed to my controller so that it finds and sends the correct email? And thank you @Oleander for your help so far!

Comment: Something like this should work: https://gist.github.com/oleander/a1162771b21cb5a8cb28

Comment: hmm. Maybe I'm not explaining this properly. I have a series of 45 different emails, (emsj01, emdr01,...embr45), and I'm trying to write one controller action that sends one of the emails that the user can select from a giant list. And again, thanks @Oleander, this is already super-helpful.

Comment: Or maybe that not the right wayfor doing this? Should I put all the emails into a model?

Comment: And when I make them all individual links on my homepage, i get a routing error. 
`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Showsender#home`

Comment: The code I posted was just an example of how to pass data form the view in to the controller/mail layer. If you dynamically want to invoke a mail method you could do something like this https://gist.github.com/oleander/a1162771b21cb5a8cb28